# KERNEL_APC_PENDING_DURING_EXIT BSOD

Tags: c, windows, kernel

I am setting a PLOAD_IMAGE_NOTIFY_ROUTINE to detect a specific image name and if there's a match, then terminate it. I am getting a KERNEL_APC_PENDING_DURING_EXIT BSOD though. The BSOD is happening somewhere in my KillProcess function which simply just opens a kernel handle with ObOpenObjectByPointer then calls ZwTerminateProcess on that handle.

What could be wrong? The code works fine outside the routine. Do I have to post it? I am getting a BSOD in my PLOAD_IMAGE_NOTIFY_ROUTINE when I call KillProcess.

Here is my KillProcess function:

```
NTSTATUS KillProcess(HANDLE ProcessId)
{
PEPROCESS Process;
HANDLE newProcessHandle = NULL;
NTSTATUS status = PsLookupProcessByProcessId(ProcessId, &Process);

do
{
    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status))
    {
#ifdef DEBUGPRINT
        DbgPrint("Process with id %d does not exist\n", ProcessId);
#endif
        break;
    }

    if (NT_SUCCESS(status = ObOpenObjectByPointer(
        Process,
        OBJ_KERNEL_HANDLE,
        NULL,
        PROCESS_TERMINATE,
        *PsProcessType,
        KernelMode,
        &newProcessHandle
    )))
    {
        if (newProcessHandle != NULL)
        {
            status = ZwTerminateProcess(newProcessHandle, 0);

            ZwClose(newProcessHandle);
        }
        else
        {
            ObDereferenceObject(Process);
            break;
        }

        if (NT_SUCCESS(status))
        {
#ifdef DEBUGPRINT
            DbgPrint("Successfully killed process with id %d\n", ProcessId);
#endif
        }
        else
        {
#ifdef DEBUGPRINT
            DbgPrint("Failed to kill process with id %d\n", ProcessId);
#endif
        }
    }
    else
    {
#ifdef DEBUGPRINT
        DbgPrint("Failed to open process with id %d\n", ProcessId);
#endif
    }

    ObDereferenceObject(Process);

} while (FALSE);

return status;
}
```

Comment: Without code it will be hard to determine error. But check you are releasing all locks, critical sections etc in the routine.

Comment: Okay, you're right and I posted it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is I was trying to terminate the process in its own context which lead to a BSOD.
Solution:

1. Create a global variable holding the pid
2. Set the global variable
3. In a system thread, check if the global variable has changed
4. terminate the process

Comment: Note that, depending on your scenario, there's a potential race condition here - if two processes needing termination start up at the same time, you might only get one of them.  You could fix this using a queue instead of a single variable.  You should also increase the priority of your system thread to make sure it runs as soon as possible, although on a multicore system that still won't absolutely guarantee that the new process won't start running before you kill it (probably pretty safe though).

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation for PsSetLoadImageNotifyRoutine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff559957(v=vs.85).aspx) says:

> When the main executable image for a newly created process is loaded, the load-image notify routine runs in the context of the new process.

(It also seems likely that when a DLL is loaded, the call is made in the context of the process loading the DLL.)

So from the sounds of it, you are terminating the process whose context you are running in.  What's more, you're doing it at a particularly vulnerable point, during a callback for an image load operation.  It is not surprising that this causes trouble.

The [documentation for ZwTerminateProcess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff567115(v=vs.85).aspx) implies that a driver *can* terminate the current process, provided that it ensures that resources have been freed from the kernel stack, but I don't think that applies in this situation.  (Also, I don't know how you'd go about doing that.)

It might instead be possible to suspend the process, and terminate it later from a system thread.

Comment: Instead, I will try injecting a DLL that will call ExitProcess().

Comment: That might also work.  I'm not sure whether it would ensure that the executable is terminated before it starts running, if that's a concern.

Comment: I was thinking of queuing an APC and injecting that way but I realized that only works on 32-bit systems and ZwSuspendProcess is not documented anywhere and is not typically a good idea to use so now I think I'm going to have to find a different injection method. I'll probably post a new question.

Comment: I was thinking ZwSuspendThread rather than ZwSuspendProcess.  At this point, there should only be the main thread (I think) and if you suspend that, no other threads are likely to be created.  But that's just speculation.

Comment: Screw that, I decided to just spawn a system thread checking if a global variable holding the pid has changed and then terminate it. Much simpler.